# My letter substitution cipher shows an error whenever there is a space in the input/phrase,to be encoded, how can i fix this?

Tags: python

So, this letter substitution cipher shows an error whenever there is a space (whitespace) in the input/phrase,to be encoded.

Here is my code:
Im quite new to python so it would be helpful for any suggestions whatsoever.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
import random

EXAMPLE_KEY = ''.join(sorted(ascii_lowercase, key=lambda _:random.random()))

def encode(plaintext, key):
    return ''.join(key[ascii_lowercase.index(char)] for char in plaintext)

def decode(plaintext, key):
    return ''.join(ascii_lowercase[key.index(char)] for char in plaintext)

original = input("PLease enter a phrase: ")
encoded = encode(original, EXAMPLE_KEY)
decoded = decode(encoded, EXAMPLE_KEY)

print("The original is:", original) 
print("Encoding it with the key:", EXAMPLE_KEY)
print("Gives:", encoded)
print("Decoding it by the same key gives:", decoded)
```

Note this isn't a Caesar Cipher, simply randomly changing the letters to other letters.
Thank you

Comment: Your key needs to contain every possible character that you want to encode (including the space). `ascii_lowercase` does not contain a space, but you can easily make a string containing `ascii_lowercase` and a space and use that instead. --- Your encoding will still fail for capital letters/numbers/punctuation marks.

Comment: Or do you want a space in the original string to map to a space in the encoded string? If that's what you want, you can add the space to the end of your key, which will cause space to encode to space and vice versa.

Comment: `EXAMPLE_KEY = ''.join(sorted(ascii_lowercase+ ' ', key=lambda _:random.random()))` adds the space to your set of known characters. You might want to add .,-?! as well
`

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response but unfortunately i still get an error when adding the extra code, it says substring not found

Comment: Please add also the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ascii_lowercase` does not contain a space, so `ascii_lowercase.index(char)` is a ValueError.

One reasonable approach is to just catch this error and return the same character. That would require breaking your join call out into a loop. You could shoehorn an `if char in ascii_lowercase` into there to keep it in one line, but that would be pretty ugly.

EDIT: like this

```
def encode(plaintext, key):
  ret = ''
  for char in plaintext:
     try:
       ret += key[ascii_lowercase.index(char)]
     except ValueError:
       ret += char
  return ret
```

Comment: Im extremely sorry but i don't quite understand what you mean could you show me by any chance, thank you for the quick reply though

Comment: i edited in an example. you'll need to do something similar for the decode function as well of course.